# About the question "Où vas-tu ?"

Tags: questions

when translating the question "Où vas-tu ?" it means "where are you going?"

"Où" alone means "where" , "vas" alone means "going" , and "tu" means "you"

why do we add "-" between vas and tu ?

which word in the question refers to "are" ?

Comment: When you say "I am going", it translates to "Je vais". Now where's the "are"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "-" is mandatory when the subject is a pronoun and the subject and the verb are inverted because of the interrogative form:

> Que fait-il ? Que manges-tu ? Qui êtes-vous ?

"Vas" does not mean "going" alone, there is not necessarily a one-to-one match between each word of a sentence in English and its translation in French. "Vas" is the verbal form in "où vas-tu", so it carries the same meaning as "are going" in English.